# Debug Alsatian test cases with vscode using ts-node

Tags: node.js, selenium, visual-studio-code, ts-node

I'm having some trouble trying to debug Alsatian test cases with ts-node
suggestions would be appreciated - as writing test cases has slowed to a crawl

I'm using Alsatian to write selenium test cases in typescript 
I've followed instructions provided here:
[debug asaltian with vs code](https://github.com/alsatian-test/alsatian/issues/250)

but it crashes on ts-node saying that module chai not defined

if anyone could help out in getting both of these working and debugging line by line in vscode would be great

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.8",
    "alsatian": "^2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
    "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
    "tslib": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

runner.ts:

```
import tapSpec = require('tap-spec');
import { TestSet, TestRunner } from "alsatian";
import { config as dotenv } from 'dotenv';

(async () =>
{
    // Load up any pseudo environment variables
    dotenv({ path: __dirname + '/../.env' });

    // Setup the alsatian test runner
    let testRunner = new TestRunner();
    let tapStream = testRunner.outputStream;
    let testSet = TestSet.create();
    testSet.addTestsFromFiles('/**/*/*.spec.ts');

    // This will output a human readable report to the console.
    tapStream.pipe(tapSpec()).pipe(process.stdout);

    // Runs the tests
    await testRunner.run(testSet);
})()
.catch(e =>
{
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

This is the old launch.json, that I was attempting to connect to the runner earlier, this configuration launches but doesn't connect.

the other provided on the alasatian github fails because it complains that module chai cannot be resolved in ts-node

```
{
            "name": "ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "run",
                "ts-node",
                "Tests/runner.ts"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/ANEX.Website.ManagementPortal.Tests",
            "timeout": 20000,
            "protocol": "inspector",

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tldr**: I created a working example in this repo: https://github.com/andrefarzat/vscode-alsatian-debug

Alsatian works by loading the javascript (or typescript from `ts-code`) dynamically, which means vscode can't track the execution, for there are no map files related to them.

I could make it work adding the ts transpilation step before the execution.

Here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Alsatian",
    "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/alsatian",
    "args": ["./dist/tests/**/*.js"]
}
```

Pay attention to `preLaunchTask` which executes the `tsc` to transpile the typescript code into javascript and put it into `dist` folder. I put the main code into `src` folder and the test code into `tests` folder.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6"]
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/*.ts",
        "./src/**/*.ts",
        "./tests/*.ts",
        "./tests/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./tests/runner.ts"
    ]
}
```

Like this, the `ts-node ./tests/runner.ts` still works and you will have the `Alsatian` debug command in vscode. Don't forget to install `alsatian` and `ts-node` locally.

I created this repo so you can test in your machine: https://github.com/andrefarzat/vscode-alsatian-debug

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach in your original question was fine, you just needed to add "sourcemaps": true, to the launch config.

Here's my config that doesn't required a tsc build each run. You could use it to run the normal example runner from Alsatian, or in this case I created a runner that runs the tests in the currently opened file:

```
        {
            "name": "Run tests in current file",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": ["test/individual_file_runner.ts", "${file}"],
            "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "-r", "ts-node/register"],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "protocol": "inspector",
        }
```

and the code of individual_file_runner.ts:

```
import { TestSet, TestRunner } from "alsatian";

(async () =>
{
    // Setup the alsatian test runner
    let testRunner = new TestRunner();
    let tapStream = testRunner.outputStream;
    let testSet = TestSet.create();
    const fileToTest = process.argv[2];
    console.log(`running tests in file: ${fileToTest}`)
    testSet.addTestsFromFiles(fileToTest);

    // This will output a human readable report to the console.
    tapStream.pipe(process.stdout);

    // Runs the tests
    await testRunner.run(testSet);
})()
.catch(e =>
{
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
});
```